# Possible to mount a RAID1 pair over USB?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, usb, raid

I have a pair of disks which I configured as RAID1 (mirrored) via Disk Utility on my Hackintosh.

I am now traveling, and took the disks with me, and want to mount them with my MacBook Pro using a USB dock like [this one](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61Ag0jD6s8L._SY355_.jpg).

The problem is that I cannot mount both disks at once. I can mount either one at a time. If I attach both, only one mounts, the other shows errors.

Am I missing something? Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so - as the USB driver does not have the algorithm to control raid1... You may be limited to using one then, once home, making both identical and connecting to the original machine.

Comment: @SolarMike But this is software RAID created via Disk Utility ... shouldn't it be independent of the controller? I thought it was just OSX writing to both drives at once.

Comment: how were they connected to the hackintosh?

Comment: @SolarMike via SATA (internal)

Comment: The problem is you're using a Hackintosh instead of a Mackintosh! :)

Comment: Can you post the output of `diskutil list` to your original question?

Comment: Also, post the output of  `diskutil checkRAID`

Answer (score 0):

As from your replies to my comments you are trying to mount via USB two drives that are normally connected via SATA with a raid configuration.

This is not (AFAIK) possible with usb...

I suggest you use one drive then, once home, you match the other drive to it then you can re-mount them via SATA and raid...

The only other option I can see is to buy another enclosure capable of raid and put them in there, but then that enclosure and the mackintosh would need to use the same algorithm for raid controls... unlikely...

Comment: There are USB RAID Enclosures.

Comment: There are indeed, but the drives are connected to a board inside the enclosure and that connection is not usb....